# Best prectice to generate the thumbnail on firebase

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, google-cloud-platform, android-bitmap

I am developing chat app.In the app user upload the avatar and all the friends get notified and thumbnails downloaded.I use google cloud storage to upload avatar.And I use Firebase function to genrate the thumbnail.
All the process work like..
First user upload the avatar and a random key is genratred and key is send to friends via XMPP message ..
The problem is key  sent to user is more faster then firebase function so it throws the exception.How to manage this situation.

Comment: Your Cloud Functions should normally be based on one or more promises: therefore why don't you wait the promise(s) to resolve and only then send the key. In other words send the key in a .then() handler which comes in the promise chaining after the ones treating the images. If you share some of your code it may be easier for the community to help you.

Comment: What is the key? What is the usage of the random key? Firebase UID? or UUID? or thumbnail name?

Comment: key is random unique image name -wonsuc